# 9 rectangles have the same area as 20 squares

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, rectangles

This is a fun little question that I encountered on a problem solving assessment:

> Q) A small area is covered by $20$ identical square tiles or $9$ identical rectangular tiles. The length of the side of each square tile is a whole number, and this is $2 \text{ cm}$ shorter than the longer side of each rectangular tile. What is the length of the shorter side of the rectangular tile?
>
> $$(A)\ 3\text{ cm} \quad\quad (B)\ 4\text{ cm}\quad\quad (C)\ 5\text{ cm}\quad\quad (D)\ 1\text{ cm}$$

Here's how I went about it:

Let the side of the square be $a$, the longer side of the rectangle be $l$ and the shorter side be $b$. From the given information, I deduce that
$$20a^2 = 9lb$$
It is also given that $a = l - 2,$
$$\implies 20(l-2)^2 = 9lb$$
And well, I'm stuck with this quadratic equation. I need to get $b$ but I don't know how.

Got any ideas, folks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Answer* :: $(B)\ 4 \text{ cm}$

Let the length be $l$ and the breadth be $b$ of the rectangle 
and let the square's side be $a$

According to the conditions,
$$20a^2 = 9lb$$ 
It is given that $a= l-2$

And according to the equation, the area must be divisible by $9$ and $20$

So it is at least $180$ [L.C.M]
taking $\text{lcm}(9,20)$ because it is the "*small area*" in question
$$
\begin{align}
20a^2 &= 9lb =180\\
20(l-2)^2 &= 180\\
(l-2)^2 &= 9 = 3^2\\
l-2&=3\\
l&=5
\end{align}
$$

Taking the rectangle,
$$
\begin{align}
9lb &= 180\\
lb &= 20\\
5 \times b &= 20    \quad\dots\{\, \because \, L=5\ \}\\
b &= 4
\end{align}$$

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Thank you for the wonderful answer. I had forgotten that the least common area was the $\text{lcm}$. I have edited your answer to make it more compatible with the site. [Please learn "$\LaTeX$ for MathJax", a very simple formatting language](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your answers better :D

Answer (score 2):

The area is $15\times 12$.  You can cover this with nine $5\times 4$ tiles or with twenty $3\times 3$s.

Comment: How did you find the area?

Comment: To quote my old friend Steven McAdam, "Trial and error is a legitimate problem solving tool in mathematics."

Comment: Note that the area must be divisible by 20 or 9, so it's at least 180.

Comment: hehe, but there's got to be another way, right?

Comment: You could solve for $a$ and then substitute $b$ with the possible values, looking which values of $b$ gives you $a$ as an integer. I prefer ncmath's method though.